# How to connect an Excel file to a Data Connection Library?

Tags: excel, excel-services, office-data-connection

In the article [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-connecting-to-importing-data-c0ad7aec-ff1a-4e48-9c21-dc18a102433f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#top), it states that an excel file can connect to a .odc file inside a DCL. I've researched for a bit and finally stumbled upon a solution that involves having to modify registry entries (below page, seems I can't post more than one link) that works for sharepoint 2010 in order to achieve doing so. The same steps would probably work the same for sharepoint 2013, however, my question is, is there no better alternative?

1. blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2010/11/15/how-to-see-sharepoint-2010-data-connections-from-excel-2010.aspx
2. martinmason.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/excel-2010-connection-files-on-the-network-sharepoint-data-connection-libraries-and-the-enterprise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525341%28v=office.15%29.aspx#part4). Turns out I can just immediately paste the direct URL of the .odc file from the Data Connection Library in the Select Data Source window. The tricky part was finding where to paste the url, so I highlighted where to paste it in case someone encounters said issue.

[image]